# How change a specific background color in a drop down menu

Tags: javascript, css

I'm creating a drop-down menu or list (don't know so much the difference) and I want to make it the way that when someone chooses the content that he wants to see and click on the image, the background of the image change color until he will change the content of the page when he will eventually click to other images to select the content. I will now paste some image here to let you see what i intend. system is the same color as the background

[image]

now that the page is showing the content of system the color changed, and even if the user will click on something else inherent to the content, the color will not change

[image]
Sincerely I really don't know what code can help me with this, be it CSS or javascript. I do not pretend that you answer me exactly like you were workers and your boss, certainly not, even simple advice on where to direct me would be fine.

```
{
    .system-rectangle{
        top: 180px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 120px;
        height: 120px;
        background: #405D6C 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
        opacity: 1;
    }

    .system-image{
        top: 194px;
        left: 25px;
        width: 70px;
        height: 56px;
        opacity: 1;
    }

    .system-text{
        top: 260px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 119px;
        height: 26px;
        text-align: center;
        font: Regular 16px/21px Oswald;
        letter-spacing: 0;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        opacity: 1;
    }
```

This are the information about the system rectangle background, the image and the text. If you are questioning why the image do not have "background" is because i delete it since it have personal information.

Comment: Please post the code that you have done yet.

Comment: What type of images you are using. What framework/library? Please update in question.

Comment: And use images from lorempixel or placeholder instead of actual images

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add/remove class on click to change background color of a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17233270/add-remove-class-on-click-to-change-background-color-of-a-div)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you want a html, css and js solution.

You can give the list items an active class and then in css you will be able to give it a different background. With JavaScript you can change the class of the item to active when it is clicked.

HTML:

```
<nav> 
  <ul>
    <li class="system-rectangle active" onclick="changeActive(this)">System</li>
    <li class="system-rectangle" onclick="changeActive(this)">Troubleshooting</li>
    <li class="system-rectangle" onclick="changeActive(this)">Other</li>
  </ul> 
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.system-rectangle{
  top: 180px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background: #405D6C 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  opacity: 1;
 }

.active{
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

JS:

```
function changeActive(elem){
  document.getElementsByClassName("active")[0].classList.remove('active');
  elem.classList.add('active');
}
```

This is just an example. This code could be written better, but If you provide your code then it is easier to give an actual example.

You can see the code in action: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/tmach/pen/OJJBOmL)

Comment: Oh thank you very much for your help. If i could i would certainly give you the code, but for major issue i cannot, but belive me, this still help me a lot.

Comment: No problem , if you need anything else you can always ask!